# Can I or How To automatically identify the pydantic schema based on a couple of key attribute value?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am playing around with pydantic, and what I'm trying to do is something like this.

I have a `BaseSchema` which contains two "identifier" attributes, say `first_identifier_attribute` and `second_identifier_attribute`.

And I have two other schemas that inherit the `BaseSchema`.

I'd like for pydantic to automatically cast my dictionary into one of the two schemas based on the value of the "identifier" attributes.

For example, in the following case, casting `some_dict` to `UnifiedSchema` with the "identifier" attributes values defined, should cast to `SecondSchema`. Currently, this does not work as expected because even though I provide the "identifier" attribute values of `SecondSchema`, the `UnifiedSchema.Data` shows `FirstSchema`.

Is this something doable even?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union


class BaseSchema(BaseModel):

    first_identifier_attribute: str
    second_identifier_attribute: str


class FirstSchema(BaseSchema):

    first_identifier_attribute = 'A'
    second_identifier_attribute = '1'
    first_schema_attribute: str


class SecondSchema(BaseSchema):

    first_identifier_attribute = 'B'
    second_identifier_attribute = '2'
    second_schema_attribute: str


AllSchemaUnion = Union[FirstSchema, SecondSchema]


class UnifiedSchema(BaseSchema):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    Data: AllSchemaUnion


some_dict = {
    'second_schema_attribute': 'b val',
    'first_schema_attribute': 'a val',
}

result = UnifiedSchema(
    first_identifier_attribute='B', second_identifier_attribute='2', Data={**some_dict}
)
print(result)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use [Discriminated Unions (a.k.a. Tagged Unions)](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions). This is a feature of pydantic>=[1.9.0](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/changelog/#v190-2021-12-31).

Answer (score 0):

You could select the appropriate Schema in the init-method like so:

```
class UnifiedSchema(BaseSchema):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs["first_identifier_attribute"] == "A" and kwargs["second_identifier_attribute"] == '1':
            kwargs["Data"] = FirstSchema(**kwargs, **kwargs["Data"])
        elif kwargs["first_identifier_attribute"] == "B" and kwargs["second_identifier_attribute"] == '2':
            kwargs["Data"] = SecondSchema(**kwargs, **kwargs["Data"])
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Invalid identifiers")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    Data: AllSchemaUnion
```